# What does this statement mean in SQL? (isnull(cast(field_name as CHAR), '') = ")

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I am looking at established queries that we have, can anyone explain what this statement means in the  WHERE clause

```
 (isnull(cast(field_name as CHAR), '') = '').
```

Comment: finding all records where a certain field is empty or null.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down each statement:

`CAST(field_name AS CHAR)` converts the `field_name` column to a `CHAR`

This value is then passed as the first argument to the `ISNULL()` with the second being an empty string `''`.

`ISNULL(CAST(field_name AS CHAR), '')`

This takes the result of the cast, and if it's a `NULL` value, returns `''` instead.

Finally, it checks if that result is equal to `''`.

Essentially, it's checking for `NULL` or empty string values in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

juergen d is correct.  I'd add that it tries to cast the field to alphanumeric before it checks if it is null or blank.  If the field's data type has no defined conversion to type CHAR, the query will error out.  Have a look at this regarding conversions/casts.

[T-SQL Data Types and Conversion Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine)